# Loading Profile Images on VK.com in ActionScript

Tags: image, actionscript-3, loading, vk

I have an iframe application in vk.com. I can use their API everything looks fine but when I want to load profile images I get Security Sandbox Error. When I print the result and errors I get This: (I am using Greensock ImageLoader)

**MYURL :** 'MY Image URL on cs408919 subdomain of vk'
**Loading CrossDomain** on cs408919 
**ScriptAccessDenied :** Error #2048 
**SecurityError :** Error #2048 
**Error :** Error #2048 
**ScriptAccessDenied :** Error #2123 Security SandBox Violation, No Policy Files Granted Access

It seems to me crossdomain.xml issue but I couldn't find right one. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's crossdomain issue, vk sub-domains for images doesn't provide `crossdomain.xml` for user avatars, but you still able to load (and add to display list as well) them. What you can't do is to access the loaded content (and set `smooth` bitmap flag for example, or `draw` the hole stage with vk images on it).

If you need the access the content you can use this "policy-hack", but it's hack, so it can be fixed in any FP update (I guess even this answer may bring closer this moment:) ):

The idea is to listen the ADDED event if image Loader:

```
protected var _prepareloaderBitmap:Bitmap;

_prepareloader.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, onPrepareLoader);
_prepareloader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onPrepareLoader);
```

And the listener:

```
protected function onPrepareLoader(event:Event):void
{
    //event ADDED fired only for Bitmap (not for SWFs)
    if(event.type == Event.ADDED)
    {
        _prepareloaderBitmap = event.target as Bitmap;
    }
    else if (event.type == Event.COMPLETE)
    {
        if(_prepareloaderBitmap)
        {
            trace("loaded image size:", _prepareloaderBitmap.width, "x", _prepareloaderBitmap.height);
        }
    }
}
```

Having the reference to the loaded `Bitmap` you can now add it instead of crossdomain issued loader.

Comment: i am now getting images form php file on my servers i hope they will let me do that

Answer (score 1):

In additional to fsbmain's answer I want say you have to add following code:

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
```