# event.target.content.loaderInfo gives error if I am accessing image from external domain(SecurityError: Error #2123)

Tags: actionscript-3, osmf

I am working on OSMF based player. I Have added logo image on top right corner of my player. Now I want to open a Link on click of logo image.

I have writen a Action script code in onMain click event

**CODE:**

```
private function onMainClick(event:MouseEvent):void{

if(event.target.hasOwnProperty("content"))

                {

                    var info:LoaderInfo = event.target.content.loaderInfo;

                    var imageUrl:String = configuration.LogoImage;//Logo url to display on player

                    imageUrl = imageUrl.split("/").splice(1).join("/");

                     if(info.url.search(imageUrl) >= 0)
                     {

                        var url:String = configuration.LogoLink;//Logo link to open in new tab

                        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

                        try

                        {

                            navigateToURL(request, '_blank');

                        }

                        catch(error:Error)

                        {

                            trace("Error occurred!");

                        }

                    }

                }

}
```

When I am giving the Logo url from same domain it's working fine(given url will open in new tab). Problem occure when I am accessing the image from external domain. A domain which dosen't supporting request from my domain.

**More information:** Logo image is displayed properly on top right corner of my player. On clcik of logo url I am getting below error. I am providing the logo url from my config file

**SecurityError:** Error #2123: Security sandbox violation: Loader.content: http:///release/XYZPlayer.swf cannot access http://www.esnipe.com/shared/help_icon.gif. No policy files granted access.

```
at flash.display::Loader/get content()

at StrobeMediaPlayback/onMainClick()
```

Please can any one help me to come out of this error.

Comment: I have done below changes in my code and it worked for me.                                                                 //var info:LoaderInfo = event.target.content.loaderInfo;             var info:LoaderInfo = event.target.contentLoaderInfo;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't http://www.esnipe.com/crossdomain.xml file that grants the access to the loaded content.

There is workaround for accessing loaded image bitmapData ([Loading Profile Images on VK.com in ActionScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632476/loading-profile-images-on-vk-com-in-actionscript/16634025#comment24053516_16634025)) but looking on your code you just need to remember the url of loaded image. Try to store it somewhere, for example in local variable or extend the flash `Loader` by your custom loader class and store the last loaded `URLRequest` object in it.

Example:

```
public class LoaderExt extends Loader
{
    private var _request:URLRequest;

    public function get url():String{return _request ? _request.url : null}

    public function LoaderExt()
    {
        super();
    }

    override public function load(request:URLRequest, context:LoaderContext=null):void
    {
        _request = request;

        super.load(request, context);
    }
}
```